# Initialize virtual environment from requirements.txt while submitting PySpark job to Google Dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I wanted to submit a PySpark job in a Dataproc cluster running Python 3 by default. I wanted to initialize the environment with the virtual env I have.

I tried two ways,
One is to zip the entire venv as and upload it as archive and submit it to the cluster. But my job was not able to find the dependencies. e.g

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --project=** --region=** --cluster=** \
  --archives gs://**/venv.zip#venv \
  --properties spark.pyspark.driver.python=venv/bin/python \
  gs://****.main.py
```

Second method was that I tried to tell spark to create a virtual env for  me and install the requirements from the requirements file provided to me as mentioned in the link

[Pyspark with Virtual env](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Using-VirtualEnv-with-PySpark/ta-p/245932)

But both the approach failed. Can anyone help? 
Plus I don't want to go the post initialization script way of Dataproc. I would really want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Would installing the requirements on the cluster help you? Starting from Dataproc image 1.4, you can add the requirements upon cluster creation:

```
REGION=<region>
gcloud dataproc clusters create my-cluster \ 
    --image-version 1.4 \
    --metadata 'CONDA_PACKAGES=scipy=1.1.0 tensorflow' \ 
    --metadata 'PIP_PACKAGES=pandas==0.23.0 scipy==1.1.0' \ 
    --initialization-actions \ 
    gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-${REGION}/python/conda-install.sh,gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-${REGION}/python/pip-install.sh
```

You can also install the full [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) by adding the following parameter: `--optional-components=ANACONDA` to the cluster creation

Comment: Not very helpful, because the requirements are ever evolving, and we spin up dataproc from Airflow, so adding metadata does not seem to be a very maintainable solution. Something like creating a jar as we do in case of normal spark application would be best.